# How to generate a lot of different codes with the specified quantity using a hash code in the database?

Tags: php, hashcode

I want to generate randomly a lot of different code with specified quantity but just save one code in a database. And when I want to use a lot of that code I just generate from one code in a database

Comment: We need you to be a little more explicit in your demand. We are not here to do the job, but to helping you to do it. So please complete your first post.

Comment: Your question is unclear and incomplete.